# Как вытащить из тега option значение его value и содержимое одновременно?

Tags: html, html-select

Как вы понимаете из заголовка, необходимо добавить в базу данных не только значение `value`, но и само содержимое тега `option`, отправив в обработчик формы их одновременно, а дальше все понятно что и как.

```
<select name="rub" required>
  <option value="0">Содержимое 0</option>  
  <option value="1">Содержимое 1</option> 
</select>
```

Конечно, есть способ в обработчике формы создавать переменную с необходимым значением, но, уверен, существуют способы лучше и "чище"…

Comment: Решение на стороне сервера есть, спасибо за него Роману Жукову.

Comment: Решение на стороне клиента найдено! Спасибо за него Ridzhi! )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно как то так:

```
$('#my-form').submit(function (e) {
        $(e.target).find('.submit-extended').each(function() {
            var submitKey = $(this).attr('name') + '_option_text';
            var submitValue = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
            var $selectText = $('<input name="' + submitKey + '" type="text" value="' + submitValue + '" />').hide();
            $(e.target).append($selectText);
        });
    });
```

// Верстка

```
<form id="my-form" method="POST" action="">
    <select name="names" id="names" class="submit-extended">
        <option value="1">Сережа</option>
        <option value="2">Саша</option>
        <option value="3">Маша</option>
    </select>

    <select name="city" id="city" class="submit-extended">
        <option value="1">Москва</option>
        <option value="2">Питер</option>
        <option value="3">Пермь</option>
    </select>
    <button>Отправить</button>
</form>
```

// Вывод:

```
Array
(
    [names] => 2
    [city] => 2
    [names_option_text] => Саша
    [city_option_text] => Питер
)
```

Если будет много селектов, потратьте время на вынос append из цикла.

Comment: спасибо большое! то, что нужно было изначально!

Answer (score 0):

Осуществляйте дополнительную обработку на сервере. Отправить нужные значения из формы простым способом не получится.

Comment: серьезно? нет способов вытащить оба значения еще на стороне клиента? жаль, если так. мб js как-то подыграет в этом случае?

в любом случае, вопрос открыть до решения на стороне клиента. а пока некуда деваться, буду писать много дополнительных букв в обработчике...

Comment: С помощью JS можно, да. Вешайте обработчик на этот select, который будет добавлять дополнительное поле в форму.

Comment: Задача еще не решена.
Сделал так:
if ($_POST['rub'] = '1') {$rub = 'nnn1';}
if ($_POST['rub'] = '2') {$rub = 'nnn2';}
...
if ($_POST['rub'] = '65') {$rub = 'nnn65';}

Все хорошо работает, но только в случае, если if'ов не более 10. Когда больше - тупо выкидывает последнее условие. 
сама форма не косячная.

Comment: `$postRub = array('1'=>'nnn1' ... '65'=>'nnn65'}; $rub = $postRub[$_POST['rub']]`

Comment: ))) возможно, надо покопаться в генеалогии. вот для этого и задаю вопросы - чтобы сделать лучше, чем смогу сам воспроизвести. новичок же, парочка месяцев стажа ;)
вот немного подправил:
$postRub = array('1'=>'nnn1', ..., '65'=>'nnn65'); $rub = $postRub[$_POST['rub']];